# Assembly's function parameter

Tags: c, assembly, calling-convention, nios

I'm actually a beginner in assembly (Nios II) and I know that a functions parameters are stored in the registers (r4 -> r7)
But I wonder if f these registers contain the actual value of the parameter or it's adress ?

for example the C function :

```
 int add (int x, int y) {}
```

Does r4 contain 'x' or '&x' ?

Comment: How do you know that the parameters are stored in `R4` -> `R7`?  Highly processor dependent.  The ARM processors have at least 16 registers to play with.  The compiler chooses the registers.  Which platform (processor) are you targeting?

Comment: BTW, are you mixing C and C++ languages?  The C++ language allows you to overload functions and operators, whereas C doesn't.  Mixing the two languages makes your program more complex and subject to more defects.  I recommend choosing one language and updating your tags.

Comment: I'm targeting a (Nios II) and I've read that the parameters are stored in R4,5,6,7 . If there are more parameters, they're stored in the Stack Pointer.

Comment: Add simple code to your `add` function, then tell the compiler to print the assembly language. :-)  This is how you get the interfacing correctly and know which registers can be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the ABI for Nios II:
https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/programmable/us/en/pdfs/literature/hb/nios2/n2cpu_nii51016.pdf
From the table, we can tell that arguments are passed indeed in registers `r4`-`r7`, and each one of them holds 32 bits. From the same document we learn that int is 4 bytes. That means that `x` will be passed in `r4`. `&x` is not passed here, as this is call-by-value. If you want to access the address of `x`, good compiler will try first to see if it's ever needed, and only after giving up, will allocate memory on the stack frame.